# Help with Stokes' Theorem (Line integral and Double Integral)

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I'm working on a problem and solved both line integral and double integral to find circulation for verifying Stokes' Theorem.

I have a problem though, my answers for both methods DO NOT MATCH, so I obviously went wrong somewhere, but I can't locate my mistake (or my understanding might be off). Help is appreciated in pointing me back towards the right direction!

S is the part of the paraboloid $z = 9 - x^2 - y^2$ that lies above the plane $z = 5$ with upward orientation and $\vec{F} = \langle yz,-xz,xy \rangle$.

LINE INTEGRAL METHOD:

$\vec{r}(t) = \langle 2cost, 2sint, 5 \rangle$

$\vec{r}\text{ }'(t) = \langle -2sint, 2cost, 0 \rangle$

$\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t)) = \langle 10sint, -10cost, 4sintcost \rangle$

$\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t)) \cdot \vec{r}\text{ }'(t) = \langle 10sint, -10cost, 4sintcost \rangle \cdot \langle -2sint, 2cost, 0 \rangle = -20$

$\text{Circulation on S } = \int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_0^{2\pi} -20dt = -40\pi$

DOUBLE INTEGRAL METHOD:

$\gamma = \langle rcos\theta, rsin\theta, 4-r^2 \rangle$

$\gamma_r = \langle cos\theta, sin\theta, -2r \rangle$

$\gamma_\theta = \langle -rsin\theta, rcos\theta, 0 \rangle$

$\gamma_r \times \gamma_\theta = \langle 2r^2cos\theta, 2r^2sin\theta, r \rangle$

$\text{curl }\vec{F} = \langle 2rcos\theta, 0, 2r^2 - 8 \rangle$

$\int\int_R \text{curl }\vec{F} \cdot (\gamma_r \times \gamma_\theta)dA = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\langle 2rcos\theta, 0, 2r^2 - 8 \rangle \cdot \langle 2r^2cos\theta, 2r^2sin\theta, r \rangle drd\theta = 0$

Thus, the two methods do not equal the same, and I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a calculation error elsewhere, but the circle is radius $2$, not $4$, so your polar bounds are too big.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oops, I did get that wrong, but it seems I now end up with 0 for double integrals. Hrm :/

Comment: The $z$ component of $\gamma$ should be $9-r^2$, not $4-r^2$. And that should fix all of your problems.

Comment: In the future, the best problem solving technique is almost always to keep the surface integral in cartesian, then switch to another coordinate system after the dot product, when it just becomes a normal double integral (there are exceptions, like if there were excessive square roots involved that polar coordinates would fix). Use the shortcut $$\gamma(x,y) = (x,y,f(x,y)) \implies \gamma_x \times \gamma_y = (-f_x, -f_y, 1)$$ to skip the differentiation and cross product steps.

Comment: @NinadMunshi If you don't mind me asking, why exactly is it that way? I did $4-r^2$ , since I thought that since z = 5, it would essentially be making $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, so $r^2 = 4$

Comment: $z$ isn't $5$, you are on the surface of the paraboloid, so it changes. If you wanted to, you could've done the surface integral on the plane and set $z$ to a constant $5$ and it would've gotten you the same answer (mod a minus sign) because both surfaces share the same boundary and Stokes' theorem says that all surface integrals that share the same boundary with the same integrand all evaluate to the same thing.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh so, we are essentially going over the surface and from radius 0 to 2, so the z = 5 doesn't matter, since when we reach radius 2, we will be at z=5. And about the comment of doing things in cartesian first, I honestly would but my teacher makes us do everything in "his way" or he docks points.

Comment: I understand, cheers! There is, however, always the possibility of you convincing him to make the technique "his" if you're good at that sort of thing.

Comment: Haha I wish, that teacher scares me, a student ran out of his class crying during lectures before. And I wanted to just thank you for the help! Just did the work again and it worked perfectly!